# Javascript - Second onclick audio play does not work

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a problem with my script for play audio onclick. I can only play **one audio at a time** (`.add` or `.remove`), but it does not play the sound of the second button.

**Only one button works at a time.**

What am I doing wrong here ...?

Thanks in advance!

```
<button class="add">ADD TO CART</button>

<button class="remove">REMOVE</button>

//----------------

var audioAdd=new Audio('add.mp3');
$('.add').click(()=>audioAdd.play()
);

var audioRemove=new Audio('remove.mp3');
$('.remove').click(()=>audioRemove.play()
);

//----------------

// For test:

/*

https://notificationsounds.com/soundfiles/8b16ebc056e613024c057be590b542eb/file-sounds-1113-unconvinced.mp3

https://notificationsounds.com/soundfiles/99c5e07b4d5de9d18c350cdf64c5aa3d/file-sounds-1110-stairs.mp3

*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consecutive clicks won't work as previous play process will be ongoing.
you can't play single instance multiple times at a same time.
you must wait till play process gets complete.

you can do something like this

```
let audioHolder = {};

$('.add').click(()=>{
  let tempIdentifier = Date.now();
  audioHolder[tempIdentifier] = new Audio('add.mp3');
  audioHolder[tempIdentifier].play();

  // removing after play process gets over so if won't consume memory
  setTimeout(() => {
    delete audioHolder[tempIdentifier];
  }, audioHolder[tempIdentifier].duration + 400 /* you can remove threshold value if you wants to */);
});

// audioHolder[tempIdentifier].duration gives audio duration
// and adding some threshold so
// it will delete after it's played ( just to be safe )

/* same for other click */
```

this will work for every click

Comment: Thanks **Excalibur**